# Is request response processing done asynchronously in http server?

Tags: java, sockets, http, server

I am trying to implement an http server in Java, I have a very basic(silly) doubt. Does the request response processing happen asynchronously ? If so, then how does client decide which response is for which request?
Suppose a client fires 3 separate GET requests, when it receives a response , how does it decide this response was for which request? Do I need to manage the session /state in client as well as server side? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTP 1.x it is simple: the first response inside the TCP connection is for the first request, the second response for the second request. If you have multiple TCP connections in parallel the happens for each of them, i.e. it is not possible to send a request on one connection and receive the response on the other.

With SPDY or HTTP 2.0 it is slightly different because request/response can be interleaved inside the same TCP connection. But this is all handled by the protocol so that it looks more like several virtual connections inside the same TCP connection where all inhibit the same behavior as described with HTTP 1.x.

Comment: Thanks , So as i understand , shall i implement each request to have a separate underlying TCP connection?

Comment: @Timothy No. If you're implementing an HTTP server you need a really good familiarity with RFC 2616. You should read that rather than just ask random questions here.